# How do i convert Flex MX Components for use in Flex Mobile

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex-mobile, flex-mx, flex-spark

I have an existing Flex Air app, that is a combination of both MX and spark components and I need it to run on an android device. Now, I have tried compiling using `adt -package -target apk-emulator -storetype` and when I install on the android device I get a black screen.

Creating a new mobile flex project and importing the existing stuff, I have mx stuff which obviously isn't compatible with flex mobile 4.6. Are there any other ways around this?

Comment: I believe this has been asked a few times already. But the bottom line is: you have to explicitly set the mx libraries on the build path and it'll cost you performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options, in order of complexity (from easiest to hardest):

1. Add the MX.swc to the library path of your mobile project.  Then you
   can use the MX Libraries in your mobile project.  Performance is
   expected bo be dismal.
2. Rework your code to replace the MX components with Spark components; if alternatives exist.
3. Rebuild your app using only mobile supported components

Comment: That's the thing, doing option 1, I still get tons of errors relating to MX.

Comment: @Doz Then you'd have to share some specific errors and we could see about fixing them.